# Vieille orthographe de louange vue dans l'Encyclopédie (loüange)

Tags: orthographe, histoire, écriture

http://enccre.academie-sciences.fr/encyclopedie/article/v5-902-1/

(ENCYCLOPÉDIE OU DICTIONNAIRE RAISONNÉ 
DES SCIENCES, DES ARTS ET DES MÉTIERS)

En lisant le lemme pertinent

> Eloge, Louange, synon. (Gram.) ces mots different à plusieurs égards
>   l'un de l'autre. *Loüange* au singulier & précédé de l'article *la*, se
>   prend dans un sens absolu; *éloge* au singulier & précédé de l'article,
>   se prend dans un sens relatif. Ainsi on dit: la *loüange* est
>   quelquefois dangereuse; l'*éloge* de telle personne est juste, est
>   outré, &c. *Loüange* au singulier ne s'employe guere, ce me semble,
>   quand il est précédé du mot *une*; on dit un *éloge* plûtôt qu'une
>   *loüange*: du moins *loüange* en ce cas, ne se dit guere que lorsqu'on
>   loue quelqu'un d'une maniere détournée & indirecte. Exemple: *Tel
>   auteur a donné une loüange bien fine à son ami*. Il semble aussi que
>   lorsqu'il est question des hommes, *éloge* dise plus que *loüange*, du
>   moins en ce qu'il suppose plus de titres & de droits pour être loüé;
>   on dit de quelqu'un qu'il a été comblé d'*éloges*, lorsqu'il a été loüé
>   beaucoup & avec justice; & d'un autre qu'il a été accablé de *loüanges*,
>   lorsqu'on l'a loüé à l'excès ou sans raison. Au contraire, en parlant
>   de Dieu, *loüange* signifie plus qu'*éloge*; car on dit les *loüanges* de
>   Dieu. *Eloge* se dit encore des harangues prononcées, ou des ouvrages
>   imprimés à la loüange de quelqu'un; *éloge funebre*, *éloge historique*,
>   *éloge académique*. Enfin ces mots different aussi par ceux auxquels on
>   les joint: on dit *faire l'éloge* de quelqu'un, & *chanter les loüanges*
>   de Dieu. (O)

C'est la première fois que j'ai vue cette orthographe. Je sais évidemment que l'Encyclopédie date du 18e siècle. Je me demande d'où provient cette orthographe et quand l'orthographe « louange » a été introduite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'orthographe et l'utilisation des accents relevaient des habitudes des imprimeurs et des traditions qu'ils suivaient.  Il y avait donc une grande variété d'orthographes possibles.

On trouve *loüange* chez Cotgrave (1611).  Si on prend le dictionnaire de Richelet dont la version en ligne remonte à 1780 et est publiée à Genève, on voit aussi *loüange* (https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k509323/f580.image). Le tréma semble avoir été utilisé en cas de hiatus, succession de deux sons vocaliques distincts.  Ceci dit, j'ai sous les yeux un ouvrage de 1754 imprimé à Lausanne où *louange* est orthographié sans tréma, comme c'est le cas de nous jours.

Pour ce qui est de la citation qu'on trouve dans la question, elle figure dans le tome V (DO — ESY) de l'Encyclopédie, on y lit *loüange*.  Ce tome est publié à Paris en 1755 (http://enccre.academie-sciences.fr/encyclopedie/section/S05-1c02a56d85f1/?p=v5-p11&). Dans le tome IX (JU — MAM), *louange* a perdu son tréma (http://enccre.academie-sciences.fr/encyclopedie/article/v9-1943-0/).  Le tome IX est publié à Neufchâtel en Suisse en 1765 (http://enccre.academie-sciences.fr/encyclopedie/section/S09-0f16912fddc4/?p=v9-p9&) par Faulche.  Autre imprimeur, autre orthographe.  Sauf que la rubrique de Neufchastel est fausse, Faulche n'existe pas.  C'est Le Breton, l'imprimeur parisien des débuts de l'ouvrage, qui continue à imprimer l'Encyclopédie de manière clandestine suite à la perte en 1759 du privilège royal, c'est-à-dire de l'autorisation officielle nécessaire à la publication.  Changement interne à l'imprimerie donc et adoption d'un autre usage dans l'emploi du tréma.

Cet usage du tréma s'est maintenu dans *poëte* et *poëme* jusqu'à la fin du 19e siècle.  Baudelaire écrivait *poësies* comme on le voit dans les corrections qu'il apporte à l'épreuve du frontispice de la première édition des Fleurs du mal (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Fleurs_du_mal#/media/Fichier:Fleurs_du_mal.jpg) (en haut à droite de l'image) .  Mais Poulet-Malassis et De Brosse, ses éditeurs et imprimeurs, eux orthographiaient *poésies*.

Baudelaire a dédicacé son œuvre à Théophile Gautier, *Au poète impeccable*…. *Poète* est écrit *poète* dans la première édition des *Fleurs du mal* mais *poëte* dans la seconde de 1861.  Cette deuxième édition sort comme la première chez Poulet-Malassis et De Broise, mais alors qu'ils avaient assuré l'impression de la première chez eux à Alençon, ils confient l'impression de la deuxième à un imprimeur parisien, Simon Raçon, qui maintient la tradition du tréma.

Voici la remarque de Claude Pichois, l'éditeur de Baudelaire dans la Bibliothèque de la Pléiade, :

- Les pluriels en *-ns* pour *-nts* (*enfans*), en usage dans *la Revue des Deux Mondes* [où avaient paru dix-huit poèmes sous le titre *Les Fleurs du mal* en juin 1855] jusqu'au commencement du XXe siècle, ne se trouvent pas dans l'édition de 1857, où l'archaïsme est modéré.  Ils ne se retrouvent pas non plus dans l'édition de 1861, bien que l'archaïsme y soit plus prononcé.  On voit en 1861 *s**é**ve*, *r**h**ythme*, *po**ë**te*, alors qu'en 1857 on lit *sève*, *rythme*, *poète*.  Cette volonté d'archaïsme est moins celle de l'auteur que celle de l'imprimeur, Simon Raçon; une volonté d'ailleurs?  Une tradition plutôt.

Answer (score 1):

L'orthographe du français n'a commencé à se fixer qu'à partir du XVI<sup>e</sup>  siècle (François<sup>er</sup>, [Ordonnance de Villers-Cotterêts](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordonnance_de_Villers-Cotter%C3%AAts)) et pendant longtemps avant, et même après le XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle, l’orthographe des mots est restée plus ou moins flottante.

Parmi les formes les plus anciennes du mot on trouve *löenge* dans [*Le Bestiaire*](https://archive.org/stream/lebestiairedephi00philuoft/lebestiairedephi00philuoft_djvu.txt) de [Philippe de Thaon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_de_Thaon) qui date du XII<sup>e</sup> siècle, le Lacune (*Dictionnaire historique de l'ancien langage françois ou glossaire de la langue françoise*) donne [*loenge*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-lacurne/l%C3%B6enge) (on trouve le mot dans le *Roman de la Rose*, par exemple) et aussi des citations avec [*loange*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/louange) dans Godefroy (*Dictionnaire de l'ancienne langue française et de tous ses dialectes du IX<sup>e</sup>  au XV<sup>e</sup>siècle*). Il donne [*loengement*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/loenge) qu'on trouve, par exemple, dans *[Horn et Rimenhild](https://books.google.fr/books?id=iwRfAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP232&dq=%22loengement%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjin9envO7jAhWwA2MBHZTNAlMQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22loengement%22&f=false)*, texte du Moyen-Âge (re)publié au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle par [Francisque Michel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisque_Michel).

Godefroy, dont le lexique s'arrête au  XV<sup>e</sup> siècle, donne une citation avec  [*louange*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/louange) prise dans les *Chroniques de Charles VII* de Jean Chartier (imprimé en 1476).

On trouve *louange* dans le *[Pantagruel](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Pantagruel/%C3%89dition_Nourry,_1530)* de [Rabelais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Rabelais) publié vers 1532 :

> avez maintefoys passé vostre temps avecques les honorables dames et damoyselles, leur en faisans beaulx et longs narrez, alors que estiez hors de propos : dont estes bien dignes de grande louange

Dans les [*Essais*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essais) de [Montaigne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_de_Montaigne) publiés entre 1533 et 1592 on trouve deux orthographes : [loüange](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k102435w/f245.item.r=louange.langFR) et [louange](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k102435w/f233.item.r=louange.langFR).

Au XIX<sup>e</sup>  siècle l'orthographe était fixée* et les romanciers du XIX<sup>e</sup>  siècle écrivent *louange*.

L'*Encyclopédie de Diderot* (comme on l'appelle communément) à laquelle tu renvoies utilise selon les auteurs des articles, *loüange* et *louange*. ([Résultat de recherche](https://artflsrv03.uchicago.edu/philologic4/encyclopedie1117/query?report=concordance&method=proxy&attribution=&objecttype=&q=louanges&start=0&end=0))

---

*Si on peut dire, car elle évolue encore, la dernière réforme date de 1996, il y a des chances qu'elle évolue encore.

Comment: Réforme (by the way) not globally accepted unfortunately as far as I know. (Thanks for this superb answer!)

Comment: @Dimitris There's nothing compulsory in it.  People may choose to be conservative and still think things should never change and the Académie Française should rule the language.  The thing is that French spelling is awfully difficult, it makes lots of French children think they're dumbasses because they can't master it, but at least with this very tiny effort at simplifying the spelling  some children can hopefully be a little more at ease with the language. And there are  people who  think it's a far cry from what should be done to democratize the French language.

Comment: Je suspecte que dans ce cas en particulier le tréma avait aussi pour rôle d'indiquer que le u était une voyelle et pas un V

Comment: @C'est fort possible.

Comment: @Laure         Pour l'Encyclopédie, vérification faite, après avoir zoomé sur le fac simile du tome 1 de l'Encyclopédie à "acclamation", louange dans "qui entonnoient ses louanges" (http://enccre.academie-sciences.fr/encyclopedie/article/v1-295-0/) présente un "u" surmonté d'un point, un demi-tréma en quelque sorte.  Il doit s'agir d'une erreur d'impression.  Il semble que la différence soit temporelle, tréma pour les parties composées avant la révocation du privilège, absence de tréma après la révocation.